# Get checkbox value instead of true of false in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have the below checkbox code and i have to get value instead of true and false when it is selected.

```
<input type='checkbox' value="Athlete" ng-model="p.selected">
```

In the console p.selected displays true or false but i need value which is Athlete.How to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `ng-true-value="'Athlete'" ng-false-value="'not Athlete'"` to achieve this.

You can find more information **[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)**.